# How do I move to Live Wallpaper preview from app?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I've been looking all over for a specific example of this and couldn't find it online anywhere.

What I want to do is: From my app click a button and move to the Live Wallpaper preview of my apps live wallpaper, so the user can choose to activate it.

Now of what I've read online, I'm to use [WallpaperManager's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html) ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER with EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT pointing to my LiveWallpapers ComponentName.

Here's my code of what I have so far.  Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?  As of now I click the button and nothing happens... (I logged it and it's actually reaching this code).

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
i.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT, "com.example.myapp.livewallpaper.LiveWallpaperService");
startActivity(i);
```

If you need any more info that I forgot to post let me know.

*I am also aware this is API 16+, this is just my case for when the phone is API 16+

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I couldn't find an example either. The first thing I noticed was that the `EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT` doesn't require a String, but a `ComponentName`. My first cut with `ComponentName` looked like this:

```
ComponentName component = new ComponentName(getPackageName(), "LiveWallpaperService");
intent = new Intent(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT, component);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SET_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
```

That didn't cut it, so I dug into the Android source code and found the following in `LiveWallpaperChange.java`:

```
Intent queryIntent = new Intent(WallpaperService.SERVICE_INTERFACE);
queryIntent.setPackage(comp.getPackageName());
List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentServices( queryIntent, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

A little debugging with the above chunk, and this is my final form...

```
ComponentName component = new ComponentName(getPackageName(), getPackageName() + ".LiveWallpaperService");
intent = new Intent(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT, component);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SET_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
```

The key was in the second parameter to `ComponentName`.

Technically, my final form supports a hierarchy of the new method first, followed by the old, followed by the Nook Tablet/Nook Color specific intent:

```
Intent intent;

// try the new Jelly Bean direct android wallpaper chooser first
try {
    ComponentName component = new ComponentName(getPackageName(), getPackageName() + ".LiveWallpaperService");
    intent = new Intent(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
    intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT, component);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SET_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
} 
catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e3) {
    // try the generic android wallpaper chooser next
    try {
        intent = new Intent(WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SET_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
    } 
    catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e2) {
        // that failed, let's try the nook intent
        try {
            intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction("com.bn.nook.CHANGE_WALLPAPER");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            // everything failed, let's notify the user
            showDialog(DIALOG_NO_WALLPAPER_PICKER);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, Thanks.  I moved away from implementing this idea as it's only API 16+, but most likely use this code at a later date.  Thanks for the descriptive answer!

Comment: I am getting an error 

12-06 14:18:26.936: W/CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER(11898): Not a live wallpaper: ComponentInfo{com.android.noisefield/com.android.noisefield.LiveWallpaperService}

Can you please tell me how to change the wallpaper if I am not the owner of that one? Instead of getPackageName() to place the package as string?

For example String packageName = "com.android.noisefield";

How to replace packageName with getPackageName()? 

Thanks sir.