# Getting error at WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I'm creating my fist Live wallpaper by following [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLiveWallpaper/article.html) tutorial. But i'm getting error `can not be resolved or is not a field` on these two lines

`WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER`
`WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT`

while trying to achive this

```
Intent intent = new Intent( WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT,
            new ComponentName(this, LiveWallService.class));
```

And compiler provides these suggessions:

```
WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER
WallpaperManager.COMMAND_DROP
WallpaperManager.COMMAND_SECONDARY_TAP
WallpaperManager.COMMAND_TAP
WallpaperManager.WALLPAPER_PREVIEW_META_DATA
```

Is any thing wrong...?

Comment: Please do note that ``ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER`` and ``EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT`` are API 16+ features.

Comment: Ok, thanks, it is fixed...

Answer (score 17):

WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER was only added in API Level 16 (4.1.2). Perhaps you have set your target SDK version to something lower than 16?

Below API level 16, you can only send the user to the overall LWP selection screen using intent action WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER, and tell him to select your wallpaper from there. You could set up your code in the following way:

```
Intent i = new Intent();

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
{
    i.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
    i.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT, new ComponentName(packageName, canonicalName));
}
else
{
    i.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER);
}

// send intent
```

Comment: can you please tell me alternate for this in less than API level 16 ?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is only one option below API Lvl 16 I know of, which is to tell the user to select your LWP from the list before sending him to the screen listing all installed wallpapers with WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I had done the above, and but still i get few errors/crash logs from 4.4,4.1 devices. why is that?

Comment: @mrfarts I had the same issue, and I have a guess as to why. I looked into one of the devices that crashed, and I saw that the manufacturer had tweaked the OS a bit. I don't know how much it was tweaked, but I think not running stock android could be the problem. A full proof solution would be to use a try/catch block, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842924/how-do-i-move-to-live-wallpaper-preview-from-app

Comment: Testing on Android 7.0, and have the same issue.