# No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.service.wallpaper.CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER (has extras) }

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, activitynotfoundexception

I am creating a live wallpaper application for android. I've written some code but I am getting following error **Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.service.wallpaper.CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER (has extras) }**

Please Help

**MyPoint.java**

```
public class MyPoint {
public String text;
public float x;
public float y;

public MyPoint(String text, float x, float y) {
    this.text = text;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

}
```

**MyPreferencesActivity.java**

```
public class MyPreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);

    Preference circlePreference = getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(
            "numberOfCircles");
    circlePreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(numberCheckListener);
}

Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener numberCheckListener = new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        if (newValue != null && newValue.toString().length() > 0
                && newValue.toString().matches("\\d*")) {
            return true;
        }
        Toast.makeText(MyPreferencesActivity.this, "Invalid Input",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
};
}
```

**MyWallpaperService.java**

```
public class MyWallpaperService extends WallpaperService {

@Override
public Engine onCreateEngine() {
    return new MyWallpaperEngine();
}

private class MyWallpaperEngine extends Engine {
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private final Runnable drawRunner = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            draw();
        }

    };
    private List<MyPoint> circles;
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private int width;
    int height;
    private boolean visible = true;
    private int maxNumber;
    private boolean touchEnabled;

    public MyWallpaperEngine() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(MyWallpaperService.this);
        maxNumber = Integer
                .valueOf(prefs.getString("numberOfCircles", "4"));
        touchEnabled = prefs.getBoolean("touch", false);
        circles = new ArrayList<MyPoint>();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10f);
        handler.post(drawRunner);
    }

    @Override
    public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
        this.visible = visible;
        if (visible) {
            handler.post(drawRunner);
        } else {
            handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        super.onSurfaceDestroyed(holder);
        this.visible = false;
        handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
            int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        super.onSurfaceChanged(holder, format, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (touchEnabled) {

            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
            SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();
            Canvas canvas = null;
            try {
                canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                if (canvas != null) {
                    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                    circles.clear();
                    circles.add(new MyPoint(
                            String.valueOf(circles.size() + 1), x, y));
                    drawCircles(canvas, circles);

                }
            } finally {
                if (canvas != null)
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
            super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    }

    private void draw() {
        SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();
        Canvas canvas = null;
        try {
            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            if (canvas != null) {
                if (circles.size() >= maxNumber) {
                    circles.clear();
                }
                int x = (int) (width * Math.random());
                int y = (int) (height * Math.random());
                circles.add(new MyPoint(String.valueOf(circles.size() + 1),
                        x, y));
                drawCircles(canvas, circles);
            }
        } finally {
            if (canvas != null)
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
        handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
        if (visible) {
            handler.postDelayed(drawRunner, 5000);
        }
    }

    // Surface view requires that all elements are drawn completely
    private void drawCircles(Canvas canvas, List<MyPoint> circles) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        for (MyPoint point : circles) {
            canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, 20.0f, paint);
        }
    }
}
}
```

**SetWallpaperActivity.java**

```
public class SetWallpaperActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_wallpaper);
}

public void clickMe(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(
            WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
    intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT,
            new ComponentName(this, MyWallpaperService.class));
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

**activity_set_wallpaper.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SetWallpaperActivity" >

<Button 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:onClick="clickMe"
    android:text="Click Me!" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**mywallpaper.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wallpaper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:description="@string/wallpaper_description"
android:settingsActivity="de.vogella.android.wallpaper.MyPreferencesActivity"
android:thumbnail="@drawable/icon" />
```

**prefs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="touch"
    android:title="Enable Touch" >
</CheckBoxPreference>

<EditTextPreference
    android:key="numberOfCircles"
    android:title="Number of Circles" >
</EditTextPreference>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

**LOG CAT**

```
02-18 21:08:07.630: E/AndroidRuntime(9406): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-18 21:08:07.630: E/AndroidRuntime(9406): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-18 21:08:07.630: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3095)
02-18 21:08:07.630: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3567)
02-18 21:08:07.630: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14224)
02-18 21:08:07.630: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-18 21:08:07.630: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-18 21:08:07.630: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-18 21:08:07.630: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
02-18 21:08:07.630: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 21:08:07.630: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-18 21:08:07.630: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
02-18 21:08:07.630: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
02-18 21:08:07.630: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-18 21:08:07.630: E/AndroidRuntime(9406): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-18 21:08:07.630: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 21:08:07.630: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-18 21:08:07.630: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3090)
02-18 21:08:07.630: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     ... 11 more
02-18 21:08:07.630: E/AndroidRuntime(9406): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.service.wallpaper.CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER (has extras) }
02-18 21:08:07.630: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1536)
02-18 21:08:07.630: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1388)
02-18 21:08:07.630: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3195)
02-18 21:08:07.630: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3302)
02-18 21:08:07.630: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at de.vogella.android.wallpaper.SetWallpaperActivity.clickMe(SetWallpaperActivity.java:23)
02-18 21:08:07.630: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317167/getting-error-at-wallpapermanager-action-change-live-wallpaper][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317167/getting-error-at-wallpapermanager-action-change-live-wallpaper

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what target you're building for but [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER) says that `WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER` was added in API level 16, so if you're using this code on an older device, it will throw this error. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317167/getting-error-at-wallpapermanager-action-change-live-wallpaper) shows how to check for the right API level.

Instead of checking the API level, you can also wrap the intent in a try/catch. While this is bad practice in general, I think it might be beneficial here, as some people have occasionally reported this error on API levels greater than 16 (although this is rare, and may have to do with the user not using a stock android ROM).

Comment: same problem in api level 23

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried to put it in try-catch and reporting the non-fatal exception to firebase. Firebase Crashlytic non-fatal tells me that this error occurs in many different Android versions (from 8 -> 13), the most is Android 11 with ~ 40% total non-fatal