# Get all live wallpapers from device

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, android-wallpaper

I'm trying to develop android app And I want to allow user to choose background of app from live wallpapers.

Now, How I can get Live Wallpapers from device?

[image: I want to get all live wallpapers from device, Can I do it?]

I want to get all live wallpapers from device, Can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can get available [ResolveInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ResolveInfo.html) list of all live wallpapers in the device:

```
 public List<ResolveInfo> GET_ALL_LIVE_WALLPAPERS () 
 {
    PackageManager m_package_manager = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> available_wallpapers_list = 
         m_package_manager.queryIntentServices(
             new Intent(WallpaperService.SERVICE_INTERFACE),
             PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    for (int i = 0; i < available_wallpapers_list.size(); i++) {
        Log.i("TEST", " " + available_wallpapers_list.get(i).toString());
    }
    return available_wallpapers_list;
 }
```

`available_wallpapers_list` will contain the amount of [ResolveInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ResolveInfo.html) same as the amount of live wallpapers in the device.   Then choose any of them in the list by creating a new [WallpaperInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperInfo.html) of desired one:

```
 private void CHOOSE_LIVE_WALLPAPER (List<ResolveInfo> available_wallpapers_list)
 {
    WallpaperInfo info;
    int index = 0;
    try {
        info = new WallpaperInfo(this, available_wallpapers_list.get(index));
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ComponentName component = info.getComponent();
    Intent intent = new Intent(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
    intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT, component);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 155);
 }
```

If you just want to be cooler and show a live wallpaper selection screen, use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER);
startActivityForResult(intent, 155);
```

Lastly you can call adb shell am command for 4.3+ devices;

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.wallpaper.livepicker/.LiveWallpaperActivity
```

by using:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("am start -n com.android.wallpaper.livepicker/.LiveWallpaperActivity");
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I want get all and display them in my gridview

Comment: refer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842924/how-do-i-move-to-live-wallpaper-preview-from-app)

Comment: suggested link having a code that gives list of live wall papers.

Comment: @mohammadrababah, Check the link further up.

Comment: did it but I didn't understand how to use the code in link, can you help me more